# Hibernate without annotation entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations

Client requires a solution without `@entity` annotation. Is a possible to use hibernate without the `@entity` annotation? I have `hibernate.cfg.xml` file with mapping entity:

```
.....
<mapping class="cz.tacr.elza.api.model.FindingAid"/>
....
```

Comment: You need to avoid only `@Entity` annotation? or you shouldn't use any annotation at all?

Comment: I need to avoid only @Entity annotation

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps. Scroll down to "Hibernate Mapping XML Configuration".

http://www.journaldev.com/2882/hibernate-tutorial-for-beginners-using-xml-annotations-and-property-configurations